# JFrame Background is moving despite having fixed coordinates

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I'm using JFrame to display some images. I've just started, and at this point I want to have a character move on screen. I have 2 files, one that extends JFrame (displays the images) and a runner file. One images is a stationary background while the other is the movable character, however, it seems that both images seem to move and the background position being stationary.

I just started using JFrame and have no idea whats going on.

This is the file that extends JPanel:

```
public class testScene extends JPanel{

    private int x = 60;
    private int y = 60;
    private boolean end = false;

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        ImageIcon background = new ImageIcon("images\\map\\TestMap1.png");
        background.paintIcon(this, g, 0, 0); 

        ImageIcon protag = new ImageIcon("images\\protag\\protag_f.png");
        protag.paintIcon(this, g, x, y);    
    }

    public int getX(){return x;}
    public int getY(){return y;}
    public boolean getEnd(){return end;}

    public void setX(int i){x=i;}
    public void setY(int i){y=i;}
    public void setEnd(boolean b){end = b;}
}
```

This is the intended Runner:

```
public class testSceneRunner{
    public static void main(String[] args){ 

        testScene scene = new testScene();
        scene.setBackground(Color.black);

        JFrame jf = new JFrame();
        InListner keyIn = new InListner(); //this is a keyboard listner

        jf.addKeyListener(keyIn);
        jf.setTitle("Test Scene");

        jf.setSize(1020,600);
        jf.setVisible(true);
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jf.add(scene);

        while(!scene.getEnd()){
            //just changes x or y based on keyboard input
            try {
                Thread.sleep(25);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if(keyIn.getPressed() == 87){
                scene.setY(scene.getY()-1);
            }
            if(keyIn.getPressed() == 65){
                scene.setX(scene.getX()-1);
            }
            if(keyIn.getPressed() == 83){
                scene.setY(scene.getY()+1);
            }
            if(keyIn.getPressed() == 68){
                scene.setX(scene.getX()+1);
            }
            if(keyIn.getPressed() == 69){
                scene.setEnd(true);
            }
            jf.repaint();
        }
        jf.dispatchEvent(new WindowEvent(jf, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING));
    }
}
```

I want the background to remain stationary and the character to move when one of the WASD keys is pressed. However, the background moves as well.